# kqemu ppa for 10.04

Tags: 10.04, virtualization, qemu

Where is a good (working, no dependency issues) PPA for qemu-kqemu and the kqemu module builder for Ubuntu 10.04?

A good PPA from which to obtain kqemu for 10.04 from would be one that has a working package with dependencies set to be handled correctly and that one can install without having to hold packages or override to keep qemu and kqemu at the PPA version. Since upstream support is gone, updates are unlikely.

Please don't suggest alternatives unless you can show they are faster than kqemu at disk I/O and networking on a VT-free machine.  I am quite aware that kqemu development has been discontinued and that Canonical has discontinued KQEMU support, leaving VT-free users who need fast virtualization in the cold.

Comment: @Downvoters: Please justify your votes. @Closer: how is this subjective? It's a clear question with a clear answer.

Comment: Agreed, don't just "bash-n-leave"

Comment: What defines a "good" PPA?

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the question in such a way that it is clear what "good" means in this context. I believe you mean the io and networking performance, but I am not sure. You should also mention what you benchmark is that this should be compared against.

Comment: @txwikinger Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](https://launchpad.net/~dnjl/+archive/virtualization) ppa:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/dnjl/virtualization/ubuntu lucid main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/dnjl/virtualization/ubuntu lucid main
```